# How to speed up rake tasks handling big amount of data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, mapreduce

I use rake tasks in my rails application, it's fine when dealing with "small amount of data" but if several scores of thousand of record needs to be retrieved / computed the tasks can take a lot of time.

Rake tasks are very easy to understand and develop and I'd really like to keep using them but is there some recommendations when it comes to huge amount of data ?

I was thinking of map/reduce algorithme for instance. Is that the way to go ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not rake that's slow.  Rake is just firing up an instance of your application and running whatever you sent to it.

You can try to re-factor your code and see if there are some shortcuts that you didn't see before.

You can try to thread or fork tasks off if it is stuff that can be done simultaneously.
I would recommend using [Spawn](https://github.com/rfc2822/spawn) if you are going to attempt this in your rails app.

Sometimes your jobs just need to take a long time.  Big Data = Big Time.

Also, if you are running your rake tasks regularly throughout the day I would recommend using using something like Delayed_Job to handle this instead so you aren't firing up and quitting rails instances each time you need to run a task.

Comment: I use Delayed_Job for big tasks. I find it helps to reduce the memory usage of a server when there is lots of processing going on.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [threach](https://github.com/billdueber/threach) and [jruby](http://jruby.org/).